# Compare two graphs based on the total number of Hamiltonian paths

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I have two graphs, say, A and B. It is given that these two graphs have at-least one Hamiltonian path. I want to compare these two graphs based on the total number of Hamiltonian paths without exhaustively finding all of the paths. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by compare? Are you trying to determine if $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic?

Comment: I mean which graph has higher number of Hamiltonian paths.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The only optimization I can think of at the moment would be to "take turns" finding Hamiltonian paths in each graph and to terminate once you can no longer find such a path in one of the graphs. This will only be helpful if the difference in the number of such paths between the two graphs is large though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will try that if there is no other way.